NodeJS Async function called once only in a loop
Following is my code structure. I have two async functions from source.js and db.js. I'm exporting these functions and calling them in test.js.
test.js calls the function async loadFromFile() to read and return a list of json data elements. For every element in the list, it then calls async writeToDB().
Expected: N number of true in console
Result: Only 1 true output in console and only one element written to the database.
// source.js
async function loadFromFile() {
    const data = await fs.readFile('/path//to/.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const ret = JSON.parse(data);
    return ret;
}
exports.loadFromFile = loadFromFile;

// db.js
async function writeToDB(data){
    console.log(data.length);    // THIS shows N data elements
    const query_str = "...";
    try{
        const response = await driver.executeQuery(query_str, ...);
        if (response){
            return true;
        }
   } catch(err){
        console.log('Error in query: '+ err);
   } finally {
        await driver.close();
   }
   // something went wrong
   return false;
}
exports.writeToDB = writeToDB;

// test.js
const source = require("./source")
const db = require("./db")

source.loadFromFile()
      .then(data_list => {
           console.log(data.length);    // This shows N data elements
           for (json_data of data_list){
                db.writeToDB(json_data)
                    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
                    .catch(error => console.error(error));
           }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));


try rewriting test.js to use async-await

I guess the finally block you are using in your writeToDB is closing the connection before other operations can complete.
Moreover you can use Promise.all to handle multiple async operations concurrently.

What exactly is the query, and where is the counter part to driver.close()?

Thanks to @"Daniel A white", @Bergi and @"Bilal Azam". Removing driver.close and calling the functions in their separate async-await solved the issue. The final code looks as follows
// source.js
async function loadFromFile() {
    const data = await fs.readFile('/path//to/.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const ret = JSON.parse(data);
    return ret;
}
exports.loadFromFile = loadFromFile;

// db.js
async function writeToDB(data){
    console.log(data.length);    // THIS shows N data elements
    const query_str = "...";
    try{
        const response = await driver.executeQuery(query_str, ...);
        if (response){
            return true;
        }
   } catch(err){
        console.log('Error in query: '+ err);
   }
   return false;
}
exports.writeToDB = writeToDB;

// test.js
const source = require("./source");
const db = require("./db");

async function process() {
    const data = await source.loadFromFile();
    for (json_data of data){
        try {
            const resp = await db.writeToDB(json_data);
            if (!resp) {console.log('Error writing to DB');}
        } catch(err){console.log('Error:'+ err);};
    }
}

process()    
    .then(d => console.log(d))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

Log output is as expected and all the data gets written to the DB as expected. However, the running node test.js on terminal gets stuck and never exits unless done manually using ctrl-c.
